# Current draw calculation from single phase 3kW transformer being fed by a 400Vac three phase source

Tags: transformer

So I have a 400 VAC 3 ph source feeding a 3 kW 1 ph transformer.

My question is... how much current will this xfmr draw with respect to the 400 VAC 3ph source?

I understand how to calculate the current in a scenario in which the 400 VAC is single phase:
i = 3000W/400Vac = 7.5 Aac.

How would this calculation differ from a 3 ph source? Would the overall current be distributed throughout the 3 phases and lower the overall current draw at the source?

Comment: How is the 1 phase transformer connected to the 3 phase source? Between single phase and neutral, so it has a 230 VAC input, or between two phases, so it has a 400 VAC input?

Comment: Yes it is between 2 phases, no neutral in this connection

Answer (score 0):

Transformers are not generally rated in kW, but in kVA.  This is because a reactive (capacitive or inductive) load connected to the transformer will still require current even though it delivers no real power.  The transformer must be constructed to carry that current.  I will assume we are talking about a 3 kVA transformer.

The amount of current drawn by the transformer is going to depend on the current drawn by the load connected to the secondary winding, scaled by the winding turns ratio.  Since you've said nothing about the load, I will assume we are talking about the current drawn by this transformer when it is loaded to its rated capacity.

As to the current distribution:

Since you are only connecting the transformer to two of the three phases of the source the current on the unconnected phase is obvious: 0 A.

The two phases that are connected will act as a single-phase source.  You have calculated the current on those phases **almost** correctly:  I = 3000 **VA** / 400 V = 7.5 A.

If there is another transformer supplying this transformer, that is where current will get distributed to the remaining phase, but how that happens will depend on the connection of that transformer (delta, wye/star, tee, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

- Connecting to the unloaded transformer will not draw 3 kW but maybe a couple of hundred watts for the magnetising current.
- If the transformer is loaded with a resistive load the power factor will be unity (1) and the transformer will present itself as a 3 kW resistive load on the supply.
- ***i = 3000W/400Vac = 7.5 Aac*** is correct for the fully loaded transformer at unity power factor.

> Would the overall current be distributed throughout the 3 phases and lower the overall current draw at the source?

No, it can't be. If the load is connected between L1 and L2 then ammeters will read ***I<sub>1</sub>* = 7.5 A**, ***I<sub>2</sub>* = 7.5 A** and ***I<sub>3</sub>* = 0 A**.

Answer (score 0):

7.5A, but it will only draw it on two phases.

Whether that bills out as 7.5A of 3-phase or 5.0A of 3-phase is between you and your power company.  (i.e. do they bill you for the watts you used, or the VA they had to generate).

Answer (score 0):

> *How would this calculation differ from a 3 ph source? Would the
> overall current be distributed throughout the 3 phases and lower the
> overall current draw at the source?*

You can only connect a single-phase transformer to two wires of the 3-phase supply hence, it's a single-phase problem and having 3 phases doesn't really help unless you use a 3-phase inverting power supply to produce a higher power single-phase output. This means that the question below is largely irrelevant: -

> *how much current will this xfmr draw with respect to the 400 VAC 3ph
> source?*